what is the org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent equivalent in Log4j 2
Upgrading Java application from log4j 1.2.17 to log4j 2.23.1. What is the org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent equivalent in log4j 2.23.1. What replaces getThreadName(), getTimeStamp(), getProperties(), getNDC() and getThrowableInformation(). What is the ThrowableInformation equivalent in log4j 2

Can you add some context to the question? Why do you need to use LoggingEvent? As for the name of the new interface, a Google search for "log4j LoggingEvent" should give you the javadoc of LogEvent as one of the first results.
